# Covariant derivative - do the link between 2 expressions

Tags: tensors

From the answer of `@levap` on the following link, 
on [Difference between Covariant derivative notations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129899/difference-between-covariant-derivative-notations), I try to understand the subtilities of covariant derivative.

`levap` wrote : " $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ "

Then If I apply this equation to the vector position $\vec{OM}$, I know this definition which makes appear the basis vector of curvilinear coordinates, i.e :

$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \frac{\partial \vec{OM}}{\partial x^j} = \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial\vec{OM}}{\partial x^k}$

that I can write also (with $\vec{e_j}$ and $\vec{e_k}$ local curvilinear basis vectors) :

$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \vec{e_j} = \Gamma_{ij}^k \vec{e_k}$ `(equation 1)`

I try to do the link between what I know, i.e I can make appear **Christoffel's symbols** like this :

$d\vec{e_i}=w_i^j \vec{e_j} = \Gamma_{ik}^{j} dx^{k} \vec{e_j}$ `(equation 2)`

How to do the link between expressions `(equation 1)`and `(equation 2)` ?

Any help is welcome, thanks

**UPDATE 1 :**

As I said in my comment, `(equation 2)` just represents the classic differential of a vector $$\vec{e_i}$$ like for example : $\text{d}\vec{e_r}=\text{d}\theta\,\vec{e_\theta}$
in polar coordinates. So in this case, I would have :

$\Gamma_{r\theta}^{\theta}=\Gamma_{\theta r}^{\theta}=1$

Concerning your answer, I need precisions about the notations that you used in your demonstration. I think that you assimilate $\{X_{a}\}$ basis to my notation $\text{d}x^{a}$ and its dual base $\{e^{b}\}$ to my notation $\{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{b}}\}$ : by doing scalar product between 2 vectors of each of these basis, I get :

$$X_{a}\,e^{b} = \dfrac{\partial(\text{d}x^{a})}{\partial x^{b}}=\delta^{ab}$$

Is this equality above correct ?

Secondly, I have a problem with the following definition :

$$\nabla_{X_{a}}X_{b} \,=\, \Gamma_{ab}^{c}X_{c} \,=\, \omega^{\,c}_{\,\;b}(X_{a})X_{c}\quad\quad\text{(equation 3)}$$

With my notations, Covariant derivative is defined by :

$$\nabla_i{V_j}=\partial_i V_j -\Gamma_{ij}^{k}V_k = \dfrac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^{i}} - \Gamma_{ij}^{k}V_k\quad\quad (equation 4)$$

So one term into `(equation 3)` is missing relatively to my `(equation 4)` : this the term $\partial_i V_j = \dfrac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^{i}}$

Have you deliberately ommit this term or is it contained in others terms in your expression, i.e `(equation 3)`.

Concerning the property (by swapping the dual and normal basis components into covariant derivative definition) :

$$\nabla_{X_{b}}e^{a} \,=\, -\omega^{\,a}_{\,\;c}(X_{b})e^{c}$$

I didn't know it : is there a quick way to proove it ?

One last question concerning the equality :

$$\text{d} \,\equiv\, e^{b} \wedge \nabla_{X_{b}}$$

Is this corresponding to the definition of total differential ?? , that I know under the form of :

$$\text{D}\,V_{i} \,\equiv\, \nabla_b\,V^{i}\,\,\text{d}x^{b}$$

with $\text{D}$ the total differential operator and $\text{d}$ the classical differential.

**UPDATE 2 :**

I am going to begin by boring you but I still have issues with some details.

I calculate the details of $\nabla_{X_{i}}V$ expression:

You wrote :

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\, (\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} + V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a} - V_{a} (\Gamma^{a}_{ij}e^{j}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j} 
\end{align}.$$

Here my calculation, I start by the following expression `(equation 5)` :

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\, (\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} + V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) \\[0.1cm]
\end{align}.$$

Up to here, we agree.

Then, for the first term of right member into `(equation 5)`:

$$\begin{align}
(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})\,=\,\dfrac{\partial V_{a}}{\partial x^{i}}-V_{c}\Gamma_{ia}^{c}
\end{align}$$

So if I add factor $e^{a}$, we get

$$\begin{align}
(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} \,=\, \dfrac{\partial V_{a}}{\partial x^{i}}\,\text{d}x^{a}-(V_{c}\Gamma_{ia}^{c})\,\text{d}x^{a}
\end{align}$$

this yields :

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a})e^{a} &\,=\, \delta^{a}_{i}\,V_{a}-(V_{c}\Gamma_{ia}^{c})\,e^{a}\\[0.1cm]
&\,=\, V_{i} - V_{c}\Gamma_{ia}^{c}\,\text{d}x^{a}\\[0.1cm]
\end{align}$$

Then, for the second term of right member into `(equation 5)`:

$$\begin{align}
V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) &\,=\, V_{a}\,\delta^{a}_{i} + V_{a}\,\Gamma_{ic}^{a}\,e^{c}\\[0.1cm]
&\,=\, V_{i}+V_{a}\,\Gamma_{ic}^{a}\,\text{d}x^{c}
\end{align}$$

So If I add the 2 terms, I get :

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a})++ V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a})\\[0.1cm]
&\,=\,2V_{i}
\end{align}$$

This result is not good because it sould be equal to (like you proove it) :

$$\nabla_{X_{i}}V = \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j}$$

At first sight, could you see where is my error in this calculation ?

Secondly, could I write :

$$\begin{align}
(\nabla_{X_{j}}\,e^{a}) &\,=\, \dfrac{\partial \text{d}x^a}{\partial x^{i}}\,+\,\Gamma_{jc}^{a}\,e^{c}\\[0.1cm]
&\,=\, \delta_{j}^{a}+\Gamma_{jc}^{a}\,e^{c}
\end{align}$$

???

Thanks a lot for your help, this is precious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a problem with equation 2 as you seem to be taking the exterior derivative of a vector. If I interpret your question correctly, you are trying to understand a relation between the covariant derivative and the exterior derivative, so let me try to answer that.

Let $g$ be a metric on some Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ coordinated by $(x^{a})$:

$$g \,=\, g^{ab}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{b}} \,=\, \,\delta^{ab}\,X_{a}\otimes X_{b}$$

where $g^{ab}$ are the components of the metric, $\delta^{ab}$ is the Kronecker $\delta$ function and $\{X_{a}\}$ denotes a $g-$orthonormal frame with dual $g$-orthonormal coframe $\{e^{a}\}\;$ (i.e. $e^{a}(X_{b})=\delta^{a}_{b}$). Let $\nabla$ be the (unique) Levi-Civita connection on $\mathcal{M}$:

$$\nabla_{X_{a}}X_{b} \,=\, \Gamma_{ab}^{c}X_{c} \,=\, \omega^{\,c}_{\,\;b}(X_{a})X_{c}$$

where $\{\Gamma^{c}_{ab}\}$ are the connection coefficients (in a co-ordinate frame these are the Christoffel symbols) and $\{\omega^{\,a}_{\,\;b}=\Gamma^{a}_{cb}\,e^{c}\}$ are the connection $1-$forms. It follows from the definition above, the duality of $\{e^{a}\}$ and $\{X_{a}\}$, and the fact that $\nabla$ commutes with contractions that:

$$\nabla_{X_{b}}e^{a} \,=\, -\omega^{\,a}_{\,\;c}(X_{b})e^{c}.$$

Then from this it follows

$$e^{b} \wedge \nabla_{X_{b}}e^{a} \,=\, -\omega^{\,a}_{\,\;c} \wedge e^{c}$$

and hence from Cartan's first structure equation:

$$T^{a} \,=\,de^{a} + \omega^{\,a}_{\,\;c} \wedge e^{c} \,=\, de^{a} - e^{b} \wedge \nabla_{X_{b}}e^{a} \,=\, (d - e^{b} \wedge \nabla_{X_{b}})e^{a}$$

where $\{T^{a}\}$ are the torsion $2-$forms. Since $\nabla$ is Levi-Civita (and hence torsion-free: $T^{a}=0$), this yields:

$$d \,\equiv\, e^{b} \wedge \nabla_{X_{b}}$$

which is a relation between the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ and exterior derivative $d$ in terms of the dual $g-$orthonormal frames $\{X_{a}\}$ and $\{e^{a}\}$.

In fact, we only really require the connection to be torsion-free and not necessarily the Levi-Civita connection. We may even relax that assumption and would find by a similar argument that for *any* linear connection:

$$d \,\equiv\, e^{b} \wedge \nabla_{X_{b}} + T^{b} \wedge i_{X_{b}}$$

in terms of the interior derivative $i_{X_{b}}$. I hope this helps with some of your questions.

RESPONSE TO UPDATE:

I feel I may be confusing matters, but let me try to explain. Let's take the case you mention: spherical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$. The metric is:

$$g\;=\; dr\otimes dr + r^{2}d\theta \otimes d\theta + r^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)\,d\phi\otimes d\phi.$$

I can define the $g-$orthonormal coframe:

$$e^{1} \,=\, dr \quad e^{2}\,=\, r\,d\theta, \quad e^{3}\,=\, r\sin(\theta)\,d\phi$$

so that the metric then becomes:

$$g\;=\; e^{1} \otimes e^{1} + e^{2} \otimes e^{2} + e^{3}\otimes e^{3}$$.

Essentially all the metric components have now been "hidden away" in the definition of this coframe. Similar I would define

$$X_{1} \,=\, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \quad X_{2} \,=\, \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}, \quad \text{and the third :}\,\,\, X_{3} \,=\, \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$$

to be the $g-$orthonomal frame. So the $\{e^{a}\}$ are 1-forms and $\{X_{a}\}$ are vector fields. Then, for example:

$$e^{1}(X_{2}) \,=\, dr\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) \,=\, \frac{1}{r} \cdot dr\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) \,=\, 0$$

whereas

$$e^{2}(X_{2}) \,=\, r\,d\theta\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) \,=\, r\cdot\frac{1}{r} \cdot d\theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right) \,=\, 1.$$

The equality $e^{a}(X_{b})=\delta^{a}_{b}$ is correct, but it is more general as it holds for any $g$-orthonormal duals $\{e^{a}\}$ and $\{X_{a}\}$, not just the inertial frames $\{e^{a}=dx^{a}\}$ and $\{X_{a}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}}\}$.

Also, there is nothing missing in my definition. Notice that what is really meant by $\nabla_{i}V_{j}$ is $(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}$: the $j-$th component of the covariant derivative of the 1-form $V$. Writing $V=V_{a}e^{a}$:

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\, (\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} + V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a} - V_{a} (\Gamma^{a}_{ij}e^{j}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j} 
\end{align}.$$

Then the $j-$th component is easily seen to be $X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$, just as you as $X_{i}V_{j}=\partial_{i}V_{j}$ in the case of intertial coordinates with $\{X_{i}=\partial_{i}\}$.

The way of proving the formula for the covariant derivative of the frames $\{e^{a}\}$ is from duality relation and $\nabla_{X_{a}}X_{b}=\omega^{\,c}_{\,\;b}(X_{a})X_{c}$:

$$\begin{align}
e^{a}(X_{b})\,=\,\delta^{a}_{b} \quad&\Longrightarrow\quad \nabla_{X_{j}}\left[e^{a}(X_{b})\right] \,=\, \nabla_{X_{j}}\delta^{a}_{b} \,=\, 0 \\[0.1cm]
&\Longrightarrow\quad (\nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a})(X_{b}) + e^{a}(\nabla_{X_{j}}X_{b}) \,=\, 0\\[0.1cm]
&\Longrightarrow\quad (\nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a})(X_{b}) + e^{a}(\omega^{\,c}_{\,\;b}(X_{j})X_{c}) \,=\, 0 \\[0.1cm]
&\Longrightarrow\quad(\nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a})(X_{b}) + \omega^{\,c}_{\,\;b}(X_{j})\,e^{a}(X_{c}) \,=\, 0 \\[0.1cm]
&\Longrightarrow\quad(\nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a})(X_{b}) + \omega^{\,c}_{\,\;b}(X_{j})\,\delta^{a}_{c} \,=\, 0 \\[0.1cm]
&\Longrightarrow\quad(\nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a})(X_{b}) + \omega^{\,a}_{\,\;b}(X_{j}) \,=\, 0.
\end{align}$$

Then since $\alpha(X_{a})e^{a}=\alpha$ for any $1-$form $\alpha$, we find

$$\begin{align}
(\nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a})(X_{b})e^{b} + \omega^{\,a}_{\,\;b}(X_{j})e^{b} \,=\, \nabla_{X_{j}}e^{a} + \omega^{\,a}_{\,\;b}(X_{j})e^{b} \;=\; 0
\end{align}$$

and the result follows.

And finally... the $d$ I use is called the *exterior derivative* and is very much related to the total derivative $D$ which you mention. They are the same for functions but $d$ extends the notion of a total derivative to higher degree differential forms; something perhaps for later study or another time.

RESPONSE TO UPDATE 2:

The key to understand your problem is to realise what people actually mean by $\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j}$. It is actually shorthand for:

$$\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j} \;\equiv\; (\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}$$

so when I calculated $\nabla_{X_{i}}V=\left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j}$ it is easy to note what the $j-$th component is:

$$ (\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j} \;=\; X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}.$$

If by $\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j}$ we meant "take the covariant derivative of the components $V_{j}$ of the vector $V$", then this would simply be $X_{i}V_{j}$ as the components are just smooth functions. Understanding this should get you over your issues and you'll find everything works out.

Comment: AloneAndConfused: for equation (2), it just represents the differential of vector $$\vec{e_i}$$ like for example $$d\vec{e_r} = \vec{e_{\theta}}\,d\theta$$ in polar coordinates (So $$\Gamma_{r\theta}^{\theta}=\Gamma_{\theta r}^{\theta}=1$$) I will try to understand your demo later but in all cases, thanks for your answer.

Comment: AloneAndConfused: could you see please my questions and remarks into my **UPDATE 1** above on my first message. Regards

Comment: Is there a little error in : $$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\\[0.1cm] 
 & \,=\, (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a} - V_{a} (\Gamma^{a}_{ij}e^{j}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, \left(X_{i}V_{a} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j} 
\end{align}$$ i.e, on the third line ??? . I would write : $$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\, (\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} + V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a} - V_{a} (\Gamma^{a}_{ij}e^{j}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j} 
\end{align}.$$

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct! Factored out the coframe just forgot to change the index. Will correct it.

Comment: :AloneAndConfused I am going to begin by boring you but if you could take a look at UPDATE 2, this would be kind.

Comment: :AloneAndConfused your last remark is very interesting in your answer of UPDATE 2 . Indeed, from the beginning, i.e my first question, I consider "the covariant derivative of the component $V_{j}$
of the vector $V$" (towards $X_{i}$) and my notation for this is $\nabla_{i}V_{j}≡\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j}$ with index $j$ corresponding to the $j−th$ component of vector V (and not the j−th component of covariant derivative $\nabla$). When you say "then this would simply be $X_{i}V_{j}$ as the components are just smooth functions", why do smooth functions imply $V_{k}\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=0$ ?