# Covariant derivative : calculation on basis vectors

Tags: tensors

Let g be a metric on some Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ coordinated by $(x^{a})$:

$$g \,=\, g^{ab}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{b}} \,=\, \,\delta^{ab}\,X_{a}\otimes X_{b}$$

where $g^{ab}$ are the components of the metric, $\delta^{ab}$ is the Kronecker $\delta$ function and $\{X_{a}\}$ denotes a g−orthonormal frame with dual g-orthonormal coframe $\{e^{a}\}$ (i.e. $e^a(X_b)=\delta^{a}_{b}$).

In intertial frame, one has :

$\{e^{a}=dx^{a}\}$ and $\{X_{a}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}}\}$

Following a previous question from this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166092/covariant-derivative-do-the-link-between-2-expressions), I try to understand in depth the notion of covariant derivative.

It is said that :

> $\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j}$ is actually shorthand for:
>
> $$\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j} \;\equiv\; (\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}$$
>
> so when I calculated $$\nabla_{X_{i}}V=\left(X_{i}V_{j} -
>  V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j}$$ it is easy to note what the $j-$th
>   component is:
>
> $$ (\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j} \;=\; X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}.$$
>
> If by $\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j}$ we meant "take the covariant derivative of
>   the components $V_{j}$ of the vector $V$", then this would simply be
>   $X_{i}V_{j}$ as the components are just smooth functions.

From a book that I am reading, the notations are different; indeed, derivative covariant is defined as (I take inertial frame) :

$$\nabla_{i}V_{j} \;=\; \partial_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$$
$$\nabla_{i}V_{j} \;=\; \dfrac{\partial V_{j}}{\partial x^{i}} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$$

Author says above definition is the covariant derivative of $j-th$ component of vector $\vec{V}=V_{j}\vec{e^{j}}$ towards $i-th$ curvilinear coordinate.

Then, in this book, the total differential of covariant $j-th$ component of vector $\vec{V}$ is defined as :

$$D\,V_{j} = (\nabla_{i}V_{j})\,\,dx^{i}$$ (with Einstein sumation on $i$ index).

So there is a slight difference between standard shorthand and shorthand in my book; I think we have the equivalence :

$$\nabla_{i}V_{j}\quad\text{(shorthand in my book)}\quad \equiv \quad(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}\quad \text{(standard shorthand)}$$

$$ \quad \equiv \quad(\nabla_{i}V)_{j}\quad \text{(standard shorthand in inertial frame)}$$

From this point, I would like to calculate the covariant derivative of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} = X_{j}\,$($\,\equiv$ basis vector $\equiv \vec{e_{j}}$) :

$$\nabla_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j} =
\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{j}\partial x^{i}} - \Gamma_{ij}^k
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$

Correction :

> $$\nabla_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j} =
>   \dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{j}\partial x^{i}} + \Gamma_{ij}^k
>   \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$

From this expression, how can I get the following relation :

$$\nabla_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.$$

??

( with the notation $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}=\nabla_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ )

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One issue is that the $\frac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^i}$ part when calculating $\nabla_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ should just vanish since the $j^{\text{th}}$ component of the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ is just the constant function $\delta_{ij}$. As for the minus sign, I have usually seen a plus sign before the Christoffel symbols in similar formulas.

Comment: :Pratyush Sarkar I don't understand what you mean by "$\dfrac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^{i}}$ should vanish". I just want to calculate the covariant derivative of vector assimilated to $\vec{e_{i}} \equiv \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$, component $V_{j}$ is not present in this calculation. Could you develop please your explanation ?

Comment: :Pratyush Sarkar You're right, I think that I should write instead : $\nabla_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{j}\partial x^{i}} + \Gamma_{ij}^k \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ because in the following expression : $$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \left( V^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \right) = \nabla_{i} \left( V^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \right) = \frac{\partial V^j}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} + V^j \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$ , If I take $V^{j}=1$, I get a plus sign

Comment: for example, taking $V^{j}=1$ allows to get the relation $$\nabla_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$ but this is not always the case, $V^{j}$ may depend of $x^{i}$ and in this situation, $$\frac{\partial V^j}{\partial x^i}$$ is not vanishing, is it ?

Comment: I mean you shouldn't be writing $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. If your vector field is $V = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = e_j$, then the components are $V_i = 0$ for $i \neq j$ and $V_j = 1$. So in the formula, your first term should be $\frac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} 1 = 0$