# Express covariant derivative in terms of exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I know there is an intimate relation between covariant, Lie and exterior derivative. I know that the covariant derivative requires more structure than the exterior, so it would be possible.
How do I express a covariant derivative $\nabla_{X} Y$ in terms of the exterior derivative, assuming the Levi-Civita connection?

Comment: The fact that covariant derivatives require more structure is exactly why it is *not* possible to express them in terms of exterior derivatives - by choosing a different metric we can get a different covariant derivative. Do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I think you are right and I just got confused. You pointed it you correctly

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166092/covariant-derivative-do-the-link-between-2-expressions/2166896#2166896) _might_ be of interest:

Comment: @AloneAndConfused thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is well known, the Levi-Civita connection can be implicitly defined via the Koszul formula. P.Petersen in his "Riemannian Geometry" gives a nice presentation of this formula:
$$
2 g (\nabla_Y X, Z) = (L_X g) (Y, Z) + (d \theta_X) (Y, Z)
$$
where $g$ is a Riemannian metric, $X, Y, Z$ are some vector fields, $\nabla$ is the corresponding Levi-Civita connection, $L$ is the Lie derivative, $d$ is the exterior derivative, $\theta_X$ is the dual covector to $X$.